# Find the robot to charge

Tags: python-3.x

There is a robot which wants to go the charging point to charge itself. 
The robot moves in a 2-D plane from the original point (0,0).  The robot can move toward UP, DOWN, LEFT and RIGHT with given steps.
The trace of robot movement is shown as the following:

```
UP 5
DOWN 3
LEFT 3
RIGHT 2
```

Then, the output of the program should be:
2

My code is

```
pos = {
    "x": 0, 
    "y": 0
}

while True:

    n = input()
    if not n:
        break

    direction,steps=n.split()
    if direction == "UP":
        pos["y"] += int(steps)
    elif direction == "DOWN":
        pos["y"] -= int(steps)
    elif direction == "LEFT":
        pos["x"] -= int(steps)
    elif direction == "RIGHT":
        pos["x"] += int(steps)
print (int(round((pos["x"]**2 + pos["y"]**2)**0.5)))
```

I am getting an error ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: What input is causing the error? `n` has to have 2 words only. Too few and the `split` line produces _not enough values to unpack_ and too many produces _too many values to unpack_ errors.

Comment: Your code works for me. `UP 5 // DOWN 3 // LEFT 3 // RIGHT 2  --> RESULT: 2` confirm that You are passing two arguments on each robot movement `direction and steps`

Answer (score 0):

```
import math

pos=[0,0]

moves={"UP":[0,1],
       "DOWN":[0,-1],
       "LEFT":[-1,0],
       "RIGHT":[1,0]}

 data = list()
```

## Set inputs

```
 num = int(input())

 for i in range(int(num)):

    n = input()
    data.append(n)
```

## Move robot on valid moves

```
for inp in data:

    parts=inp.split()    
    mv=parts[0]
    val=parts[1]
    if mv in moves and val.isnumeric():
        pos[0] += moves[mv][0]*int(val)
        pos[1] += moves[mv][1]*int(val)
```

## get distance

```
distance=math.sqrt(pos[0]**2 + pos[1]**2)

print(round(distance))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
pos = {
    "x": 0, 
    "y": 0
}
z=int(input())
c=0
while (c!=z):

    n = input()
    c=c+1
    if not n:
        break

    direction,steps=n.split()
    if direction == "UP":
        pos["y"] += int(steps)
    elif direction == "DOWN":
        pos["y"] -= int(steps)
    elif direction == "LEFT":
        pos["x"] -= int(steps)
    elif direction == "RIGHT":
        pos["x"] += int(steps)
print (int(round((pos["x"]**2 + pos["y"]**2)**0.5)))
```

Comment: Some human readable description of your answer would have been nice!

Answer (score 0):

I got an alternate solution:

```
pos = {"x":0,"y":0}
num = int(input())

for _ in range (num):
    command =  input().split(" ")      # ACCEPT MOVEMENT COMMAND AND STORE AS A LIST
    if command[0] == "UP":             # EXTRACT DIRECTION AND COMPARE
        pos["y"] += int(command[1])    # INCREMENT/DECREMENT APPROPRIATE CO-ORDINATES
    if command[0] == "DOWN":
        pos["y"] -= int(command[1])
    if command[0] == "LEFT":
        pos["x"] -= int(command[1])
    if command[0] == "RIGHT":
        pos["x"] += int(command[1])

print(int(round((pos["x"]**2 + pos["y"]**2)**0.5)))   # DISTANCE FROM ORIGIN
```

maybe this is easier to understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
import math
x=int(input())
dict1={"UP":0,"DOWN":0,"LEFT":0,"RIGHT":0}
for i in range(x):
    y=input().split()
    dict1[y[0].upper()]=int(y[1])
#print(dict1)

dist=math.sqrt((dict1["UP"]-dict1["DOWN"])**2 + (dict1["LEFT] - dict1["RIGHT"])**2)
dist=int(round(dist))
print(dist)
```

Answer (score 0):

`dict= {"x":0, "y":0}`

```
while True:
a = input("enter your direction for the robot(UP, DOWN)etc: ")
if a=="UP":
    dict["y"]+=5    
elif a=="DOWN":
    dict["y"]-=3
elif a=="LEFT":
    dict["x"]-=3
elif a=="RIGHT":
    dict["x"]+=2
elif a=="DIST":
    d=math.sqrt(dict["x"]**2 + dict["y"]**2)
    print(d)
    break
else:
    print("invalid entry, try again")
```

Comment: Please write some description with your answer. Please read the guidelines carefully https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer